# My Windows 11 stopped working. It was working with Linux on same hard drive in different partitions for last few years

Tags: windows, windows-11

Recently my Windows 11 stopped working. Linux is still working on the same hard drive in a different partition.
When I try to start Windows, it gives following messages.
"Preparing Automatic Repair, Diagnosing your PC. Automatic Repair. Your PC did not start correctly. It gives options, I try "Repair" It does not succeed. I try "Advanced options, Troubleshoot, Reset this PC keeping files, local reinstate, getting things ready, Reset this PC, Reset, Resetting this PC 2%....33%, undoing changes"
Then it is back to not working. I tried several times. The same options were shown repeatedly. Please suggest what I should do. Thanks

Comment: what changes in either operating system did you make "recently" - i.e. were either operating system updated "recently"?

Comment: And... Have you tried to boot Windows directly (UEFI settings > Boot menu)? If not then why not? If so were the results the same? In that case you'll need to boot Windows installation media and use the tools to repairs the installation or simply reinstall. Problems of that nature seldom, if ever, are related to the dual-boot.